# 403 Forbidden Apache

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

I've searched a lot about this but none of the solutions I encountered helped.

First time using Wampserver with Apache and PHP and my localhost displays:

```
403 Forbidden. 

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) PHP/5.6.35 Server at localhost Port 80
```

Also when I run httpd via cmd it shows:

```
C:\apache\bin>httpd
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network 
address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind 
to address [::]:80
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network 
address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind 
to address 0.0.0.0:80
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I uninstalled Skype because I saw it might have problems with port 80.

I've tried to Allow access all granted in httpd docs but didn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: if it has a .htaccess file in the root folder of the web server, enter the content, and also insert the apcace configuration file. thank you

Comment: you could try to change the door, port 80 is reserved by os, it could prevent it from opening. or you could start the webserver as admin / root

Comment: If you get the first error message, Apache is already running (that's whats giving you the 403 message). Do you actually have any index-file in the web root?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into Apache and change all port from 80 to 8080.